# How to prepare Stevia leaves for consumption?

Tags: culinary-uses

I have a Stevia plant growing on my deck and I'd love to use it in a recipe. Does anyone know a way to use Stevia leaves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stevia leaves are commonly cut, then hung for drying, then either ground up into little flakes and used sparingly in drinks such as teas or recipes. The leaves themselves are also very commonly used unground as garnish in drinks as well as added to recipes.

Just remember to compensate accordingly for the extra sweetness they will provide, and you really cant go wrong with some experimentation at first.

In terms of a particular recipe I'm not really sure what to recommend so hopefully this is still helpful.

Comment: Thanks :) I notice that when I eat the leaves as-is, they have a bit of a bitter aftertaste - does drying affect it?

Comment: I know that if you harvest before the plant flowers you can have a lower bitter taste as this is when they are the sweetest.  The stems and veins contain alot of the 'bitter taste' so removing them can also help lower it.   The actual drying should be more of a preservation of the flavors so you should do it same day you pick. The drying process is often hanging them upside down in good circulation.

Comment: In my experience, stevia always has a bitter aftertaste. There are commercial stevia sweeteners that are supposed to be less bitter, but to me, they all taste worse than saccharin.